# Determining Convergence of Power Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, statistics, power-series

> Flip a fair coin until you get the first "head".  Let X represent the number of flips before the first head appears.  Calculate E[X].

So I solved this problem and you get a power series:

$E[X] = 1*0.5 + 2*0.5^2 + 3*0.5^3+ ...$

This is basically of the form $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}x_i(0.5)^i.$

I flipped open my calculus book to review how to solve this series but I didn't find anything on how to calculate the limiting value for a power series, just the radius of convergence.

I see for a sum of infinite geometric series, the value is:

$S_n = a+ ax + ax^2 + ... + ax^n + ... = \cfrac{a}{1-x}$ for |x| < 1.

Can someone please tell me the general approach if there is one for a power series?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: Set $a=1$ and differentiate both sides of the expression $1+x+x^2+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-x}$. You will get something very close to what you want.

Comment: Thank you @AndréNicolas!  Is there anything that you don't know?

Comment: Note that coincidentally essentially the same question was asked and answered 3 or 4 questions ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general approach to this kind of problem is to sum the series by repeated differentiation and multiplication.  This should produce a solution to any series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^k x^n$, and, therefore, any series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}p(n)x^n$ .  As an example, let's solve your specific series, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^n$.  To solve this, recall the formula for a simple geometric series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac1{1-x}$$

Now, differentiate both sides with respect to x to get:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}=\frac1{(1-x)^2}$$

Next, multiply both sides by x, and we have:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^{n}=\frac x{(1-x)^2}$$

Finally, substitute in $x=1/2$ to get $E[X]=2$, which is the correct result for the expectation of a geometric distribution with p=0.5.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes thank you @logosintegralis!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

We give an alternative way to do the calculation. The expectation exists, since the series converges. Let it be $a$. On your first toss, two things can happen: (i) You get a head, so $X=1$ or (ii) You get a tail, have wasted a toss, and your expected number of *additional* tosses is $a$. So with probability $0.5$, your expectation is $1$, and with probability $0.5$ it is $1+a$. It follows that
$$a=(0.5)(1)+(0.5)(1+a).$$
Solve this linear equation for $a$. We get $a=2$.

**Remark:** We interpreted the phrase "before the first head appears" in the conventional sense, where the successful toss is counted. If we interpret *before* as meaning strictly before, the power series expression becomes a little nicer, and the mean turns out to be $1$.

Comment: I didn't understand this explanation, but your hint on differentiating helped me solve the problem.  Thank you.

Comment: The argument used what is called formally *conditional expectation*. If with probability $p$ your expectation is $c$, and with probability $1-p$ it is $d$, then the (unconditional) expectation is $pc+(1-p)d$.